# upgrading to TFS 2017 (SQL Server 2014) from a TFS 2015 (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: team-foundation-server

I am upgrading to TFS 2017 (SQL Server 2014) from a TFS 2015 (SQL Server 2012). I did install and configure TFS 2017 on the new box. Can I use the TFS backup and restore tool to restore database backup from TFS2015 box to TFS2017 box? Or do I need to unconfigure TFS 2017 ?

Answer (score 1):

You should unconfigure TFS 2017, and clean up the databases.

Use "tfconfig install /unconfigure:all" to remove the config and then delete all of the database. You should then be able to use the database restore tool.